# Attribute error while creating class

Tags: python

This example is written in Introduction to Computation & Programming using Python by John V. Guttag

```
class IntSet(object):
        def _init_(self): 
              self.vals= [] 
        #Rest of the code is fine 

        def insert(self,x): 
              if not x in self.vals:
                    self.vals.append(x)


s= IntSet() 
s.insert(3)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhimanyuaryan/Python/Classes/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    s.insert(3)
  File "/Users/abhimanyuaryan/Python/Classes/main.py", line 13, in insert
    if not e in self.vals:
AttributeError: 'IntSet' object has no attribute 'vals'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `__init__` instead of `_init_`

Comment: oops thanks for helping...can you also tell why object is passed as parameter in IntSet class?

Comment: @codejam.tk that's not a parameter, that's a superclass. Have you tried reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor should be `__init__` with two underscores `_` on each side.  Because you left those out Python couldn't find the constructor on `s= IntSet()`, and therefore never created the `self.vals` variable.  All "magic methods" of Python classes will have the same format with two underscores `_` on each side as detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you didn't actually override the initializer (__init__), as you used single underscore instead of double underscore on each side, so you practically just created an additional method named "_init_".

Thus when you run the code, you use the default object initializer to instantiate IntSet.
Just change _init_ to __init__ and it will work.

E.G.

```
class IntSet(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.vals = []
  .
  .
  .
  (rest of code)
```